# DB update in model giving error, Property is not defined

Tags: php, yii

I have a model class that looks like this

```
    class Payment extends CActiveRecord
    {
    
    ...
    ...
    ...
    public function setCountry($country) {
    
            $uid = (int) Yii::app()->user->id;
            
            $model = $this->model()->findByAttributes(
                array(
                    'uid' => $uid,
                )
            );
            $model->country = strtoupper($country);
    
            $model->update();
        }
    }
```

in my controller i'm calling the `setCOuntry` function like this

```
Payment::model()->setCountry('us');
```

But Yii is giving me this error.

```
Property "Payment." is not defined.
```

on this line `$model->update();`

How do i update my table in the same model? What am i missing here? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Makes sure country property/field should be existing on database table and model.

Print model attributes and check country attribute exist on model and then try to save